# Sybase ASE 16.0 BCP in character problem

Tags: sybase, bcp, sybase-ase

I am using SYBASE ASE 16.0 and in my tables i have some values like

> "KOCAELİ", "İZMİR", "TALATPAŞA"

. They are readable in csv file however when i put database with bcp in command, i have mistakes which are

> "KOCAEL0", "0ZM0R", "TALATPA^A

my command is :

```
bcp ME_DEV_TRUNK_DB..aktar2 in list.csv -b10000 -c -t',' -r\\n -Usa -SMYDB1 -Jiso88599 -F2
```

How can i fix and input data into database?

Comment: What's your dataserver default character set and sort order? What tool are you using to look at the data once the `bcp` has completed, and have you made sure that tool is using the correct character set (ie, have you verified the issue is not with your viewing tool as instead of the database)?

Comment: I look data with Aqua Studio.  Character set is in DB :iso88599

Comment: Is Aqua Studio configured to use iso88599?  Do other tools (eg, command line `isql` that comes with ASE) display the characters correctly when configured to use iso88599?